# Python- Check if user typed one of those words that are in the list

Tags: python

How do i check if the user wrote a word that matches any of the words in a list i made in another file?

```
file1 = open('Screen.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('Battery.txt', 'r')
words1 = str(file1.read().split())
words2 = str(file2.read().split())
print(words1)

user = str.lower(input("type what is your problem?"))
if any(user in words1 for words1 in user):  #This part is probably the problem
    print("answer")
```

if the user types any of the words that are listed in a list in another file then the program should display answer. if the user does not type any of the words that are in the list then don't print anything

sorry i was not precise enough, what i meant is that i want the user to write a sentense like "the phone screen is broken" and then i want the program to look in the lists of words called words1 and words2 and then to find the word "screen" inside of the words1 file.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kH8i.png)

Comment: `if words1.count(user) > 0 or words2.count(user) > 0`

Comment: Loop within `any()` is unordered. Can you be specific on which list you need to do the check?

Comment: @dawid 777777777 were you able to solve this? If yes, you may mark an answer by clicking on the tick sign to accept it, cheers

Answer (score 0):

`count(element)`:

> function returns the occurrence count of given element in the list. If
>   its greater than 0, it means given element exists in list.

example:

```
user = 'c'
words1 = ['a','b']
words2 = ['c', 'd']
if words1.count(user) > 0 or words2.count(user) > 0:
    print("answer")
```

OR

```
if user in words1 + words2:    # search the string in the concatenated list
    print("answer")
```

**EDIT:**

The concatenated solution could cause memory issues, we could also opt for `chain` using itertools:

```
from itertools import chain
if user in chain(words1, words2):
    print("answer")
```

Answer (score 0):

After converting both files into strings words1, words2 just follow these steps:

For this you must download nltk package

```
pip install nltk
```

Then

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

w1=set(word_tokenize(words1))
w2=set(word_tokenize(words2))

if input() in w1.union(w2):
   print("something")
```